# Am I allowed to say Goodbye in Parenting Meta?

Tags: discussion

I really just wanted to say goodbye and thank you, everyone of you who hang around Parenting. It's been a pleasure reading your posts and they have helped me in my own parenting. I hope I have also contributed something of value.

I had to make this a question, but I most likely won't be around to read the answers, or see whether the question gets closed because it isn't a real question :-) I'm leaving Parenting around midnight UTC for an unknown amount of time.

I can no longer support a company who IMO seriously misunderstands a lot about people (see the Monica Cellio/ CoC fiasco). I could go on, but I'm tired of it and I don't want to infect Parenting with this sickness.

This has nothing to do with anything that ever happened on Parenting, I think this community is a healthy place. Please keep it that way. I wish the site and all of you the best, and hope to see you again sometime down line.

Goodbye.

Comment: Yes, it's allowed, and I don't know how to vote on this! I'm afraid if I upvote, it will look like I'm glad you're leaving, and if I downvote, that I don't think this is appropriate for meta. It is appropriate, and I am very sad to see you go.

Comment: I'm voting to close... just kidding. It's entirely appropriate for meta (and even if it wasn't, I wouldn't take action). I understand why you leave, but it's still sad. Parenting.SE has few high-rep users who are actively involved. I still upvoted, just because upvotes are nice, aren't they?

Comment: I'm so sorry you won't get this comment and the complete irony of it. Since you've not posted much in meta, the answer box starts wit this advice: "Pascal is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct." Lol! (We need to take our laughter were we can get it, right?)